# Kivy : How can i reset checkbox active value

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

When I switch between screens i want to clear the check boxes marked.Marked boxes remain checked when i change screens.

I think my problem will be solved if I find a way to change the activation of checkboxes when I switch to another screen.

But I don't know how to do that.

My Code also has a certain number of checkboxes I choose only six of them. The functions in my main file are to calculate them.

My main.py

```
class SkillChose(Screen):
    checkboxvalues = {}
    for i in range(1, 21):
        checkboxvalues["s{}".format(i)] = -2
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(SkillChose,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.click_count = 0
        self.skills=[]

    def click_plus(self,check,id):
        if check is True:
            self.click_count+=1
            self.checkboxvalues[id]=1
        return True
    def click_extraction(self,id):
        if self.checkboxvalues[id]==1:self.click_count-=1
        self.checkboxvalues[id]=0
        return False
    def control(self,id):
        if id==0:return False
        count=0
        for open in self.checkboxvalues.values():
            if open==1:
                count+=1
        for i,j in self.checkboxvalues.items():
            print(i,j)
        if count<6:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

my.kv file

```
<SkillChose>:
    name:"skill"
    BoxLayout
        ScrollView:
            size: self.size
            GridLayout:
                id: grid
                size_hint_y: None
                row_default_height: '50sp'
                height: self.minimum_height
                cols:2
                Label:
                Label:
                Label:
                    text:"skill1"
                CheckBox:
                    value:"s1"
                    active:(root.click_plus(self.active,self.value) if root.control(self.value) else False ) if self.active else root.click_extraction(self.value)
                Label:
                    text:"skill2"
                CheckBox:
                    value:"s2"
                    active:(root.click_plus(self.active,self.value) if root.control(self.value) else False ) if self.active else root.click_extraction(self.value)
                Label:
                    text:"skill3"
                CheckBox:
                    value:"s3"
                    active:(root.click_plus(self.active,self.value) if root.control(self.value) else False ) if self.active else root.click_extraction(self.value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following enhancements (kv file & Python script) are required to clear the `CheckBox`'s attribute `active` when leaving a screen.

### kv file

Use `ScreenManager` `on_leave` event to invoke a callback e.g. `reset_checkbox()`

#### Snippets - kv file

```
<SkillChose>:
    name:"skill"

    on_leave: root.reset_checkbox()

    BoxLayout:
        ...
```

### Py file

- Add import statement, `from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox`
- Use `for` loop to traverse the children of `GridLayout:` via `ids.grid`
- Use `isinstance()` function to check for `CheckBox` widget

#### Snippets - Py file

```
class SkillChose(Screen):
    ...
    def reset_checkbox(self):
        for child in reversed(self.ids.grid.children):
            if isinstance(child, CheckBox):
                child.active = False    
    ...
```